# C# Best way to user resource file for client side in mvc - 4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project, in which, for internationalization, i am using resource file (.resx) for my validation messages and for info messages. It works well on server side and for client side also i want to use the same approach. I am pretty new in such kind of stuffs. I learn these great blogs t get info about this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

For client side i was thinking to do the ajax call to get the resource file as a json. And than use it on the client side. I just want to know about the approach i was thinking. Is it good and optimized or is there any other better way to achieve the same ?

Please let me know the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I apparently rambled on a bit here, short version is if you need localized strings in Javascript then I would recommend using hidden fields to hold the translated values and grab from them.

There are two parts to handling multiple languages, globalization and localization.

Globalization is handling numbers and related things based on the current culture's norms. For instance in the US we would write $1,000.00 while in Germany they would (assuming my Googling is correct) write $1.000,00 (currencies are also a complex topic but don't fall under either IMO).

This is the bit that we have lots of Javascript libraries for since Javascript often has to render some compound data as user output (for instance summing up the items in a cart without requiring a page load)

Localization is handling the text of your page, this is the area where Javascript is very weak. The reason it is weak is because you really shouldn't need it. The only place where Javascript localization is required is when you are rendering textual output from Javascript, which is an odd source for text to be displayed on a webpage.

What I have done when I needed localize Javascript strings (say for a prompt) is to use a hidden field which is populated by the server side localization tools. It seems to mesh well with then normal process and solves the issue cleanly. While not ideal it also helps minimize constant strings in your Javascript, which are a localization nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas for this problem:

1. One idea ist to make a controller that renders a java-script file which has one object with all resources you need for a page (you can also group them in another way, but it is not a good idea to have one big js-resource-file in your application).

This controller gerenates an object like this:

```
var resources = {};
resources.Yes = 'Yes';
resources.No = 'No';
resources.DeleteUser = 'Delete User?';
```

you can access this easily in your script:

```
if (alert(resources.DeleteUser)) {
   // Delete User
}
```

You need a clever way to generate these files, for example you could automatically scan your jscript for resource-acess-statements and generate these files.

1. Write a custom handler for your jscript files, scan it for all resource-access-statements, e.g. resources.[...] and replace it with the localized version. Deliver one jscript file for each language and use caching and a cache-dependency to your jscript file to improve performance.